# One Javascript Line Causes the Rest of the File to Not Function

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript file that I use to check the input of a form. However, when I uncomment the commented line, the javascript file does not function properly, and the form is submitted even if some of the fields are blank. In fact, the Javascript file doesn't even make it to the second alert function. What is going on?

```
function checkLogin()
{
    alert("HERE");
    //document.getElementById("errors").style.display = "none";
    var form = document.getElementById("form1");
    var problems = false;
    document.getElementById("errorJS").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("errorJS").innerHTML = "";
    alert("test");
    if(form.email.value.length < 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("errorJS").innerHTML += "Please enter your email address. <br />";
        problems = true;
        document.getElementById("errorJS").style.display = "block";
    }
    if(form.pword.value.length < 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("errorJS").innerHTML += "Please enter your password.";
        problems = true;
        document.getElementById("errorJS").style.display = "block";
    }
    alert(!(problems));
    return !(problems);
}
```

That was it, the line was returning null. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Does `errors` exist? All the others are `errorJS`

Comment: You should see a javascript error at that line, likely because the element doesn't exist. That's how javascript works ... fix the error and the rest of the code will execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you don't exactly define what "does not function properly" means, and you have provided no error info (which the browser surely supplied to *you*), I would say that `document.getElementById("errors")` is returning null. This would mean that no element exists in your document with the ID of `errors`.

A check of whether `document.getElementById("errors")` returned something usable before attempting to access properties thereon would be a good step forward. Ensuring your document is as you assume it to be would be another.

Comment: After the commented line, the function returns true, instead of continuing through the lines and returning false if one of the fields is left blank.

Comment: That's if the commented line is uncommented.

Comment: The function does not return true, it halts and the browser continues with the default action.

Comment: @user532493: How can you say it returns true?

Answer (score 3):

Short: It is throwing an error somewhere (supposedly in the outcommented line), which halts the script's execution (does not alert, does not stop submitting).

This error seems to be that `document.getElementById("errors")` returns `null`, throwing an error when trying to access the `style` property of it. You should catch that case:

```
var errors = document.getElementById("errors");
if (errors)
    errors.style.display = "none";
```